# Pulling the 'ExternalImageId' data when running search_faces_by_image

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm fairly new to AWS and for the past week, been following all the helpful documentation on the site.

I am currently stuck on bring unable to pull the External Image Id data from a Reko collection after a 'search face by image', I just need to be able to put that data into a variable or to print it, does anybody know how I could do that?

Basically, this is my code:

```
import boto3
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
bucket = 'bucketname'
collectionId = 'collectionname'
fileName = 'test.jpg'
threshold = 90
maxFaces = 2

admin = 'test'

targetFile = "%sTarget.jpg" % admin
imageTarget = open(targetFile, 'rb')

client = boto3.client('rekognition')
response = client.search_faces_by_image(CollectionId=collectionId,
                                        Image={'Bytes': imageTarget.read()},
                                        FaceMatchThreshold=threshold,
                                        MaxFaces=maxFaces)

faceMatches = response['FaceMatches']
print ('Matching faces')
for match in faceMatches:
    print ('FaceId:' + match['Face']['FaceId'])
    print ('Similarity: ' + "{:.2f}".format(match['Similarity']) + "%")
```

at the end of it, I receive:

```
Matching faces
FaceId:8081ad90-b3bf-47e0-9745-dfb5a530a1a7
Similarity: 96.12%

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What I need is the External Image Id instead of the FaceId.

Thanks!

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rekognition.html#Rekognition.Client.search_faces_by_image indicates that each `FaceMatches` member in the response has a `Face` with an `ExternalImageId`.  The structure seems straightforward, so we need some clarification of this question -- show your code, and the unexpected results of running that code, please.

Comment: Updated the OP, thanks again!

Comment: Would the solution not simply be `print ('ExternalImageId:' + match['Face']['ExternalImageId'])` inside the `for match` loop?

Comment: Aye, turns out 
('anystringhere:' + match['Face']['ExternalImageId'])
is the way to do it!

Thanks alot!